# Loading Google Compute image onto VMWare

Tags: vmware-server, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to load a Google Compute image onto a VMWare (6.5) server.
The image is a .raw file. 
However, I can't find .raw mentioned in any VMWare instructions, and more importantly, the ext HDD doesn't show anywhere in the VMWare console to load from! (It does show in the BIOS, so is present)

Comment: raw usually means it's not a "format", assuming [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image) is applicable it's like a `dd` of a disk.

Comment: That makes sense, as it was produced with a dd. Is there a way of getting it onto VMWare - using this file or another method i.e. getting a supported format from Google?

Comment: Well, you could create a new parition and use `dd` to copy the image into that partition. I'm not familiar with Google Compute and have no idea what's in the image... so, do it at your own risk.

Comment: A new partition on my VMW server? How would I then install that as a VMW instance?

Comment: Setup the instance, boot a linux, mount a share which makes it accessible and use `dd` to copy it. Alternatively you might have some option to convert the file.

Comment: Jeebus, people. He already has the partition as a raw dump. There is no need to export it. Martin, just follow vmware's own instructions on converting physical partitions to vmware instances. You can use VCenter Converter to do the actual conversion https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/6_2_0